# tuning huge delete operation on sql server table

Tags: sql-server, delete

I am performing a delete operation on very large sql server table based on query as discussed below.

```
delete db.st_table_1
where service_date between(select min(service_date) from stg_table)
                   and (select max(service_date) from stg_table);
```

stg_table and stg_table_1 doesn't have indexes on service_date.

both of these tables are loaded with million rows of data and delete operation is taking lot of time. Requesting your suggestion to improve the performance of this query.

I referred to strategy described in below question but couldn't understand how to implement it.

[How to delete large amount of data in sql server without data loss?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/236638/how-to-delete-large-amount-of-data-in-sql-server-without-data-loss)

requesting your kind suggestion on this.

Update:

```
select * into db.temp_stg_table_1
from db.stg_table_1
where service_date not between( select min(service_date) from db.stg_table)
                             and (select max(service_date) from db.stg_table);

exec sp_rename 'stg_table_1' , 'stg_table_1_old'

exec sp_rename 'temp_stg_table_1' , 'test_table_1'

drop table stg_table_1_old
```

how about if go with above logic to delete the millions of records. any advantages and disadvantages with that.

Comment: Could you add the estimated / actual execution plan to [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? Indexing could speed up your query, but larger deletes can take longer. How many rows are you deleting? You should consider deleting in [batches](https://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/)

Comment: I don't have access to net on server so may not be able to paste the plan. I have to delete 36994798 records from st_table_1 table. Do I need to create a index on service_date for both the tables.

Comment: How much data you'd like to retain? If <= 10%, maybe to use TRUNCATE approach. 1-SELECT 10% data INTO temp; 2-Remove FKs;3-TRUNCATE table;4-Recreate FKs;5-INSERT all data in temp back to your table

Comment: @ Randi Vertongen. Thanks for your valuable inputs. I am accepting the answer. what if I delete rows based on below statements. select * into db.temp_stg_table_1
from db.stg_table_1
where service_date not between( select min(service_date) from db.stg_table)
                             and (select max(service_date) from db.stg_table);

exec sp_rename 'stg_table_1' , 'stg_table_1_old'

exec sp_rename 'temp_stg_table_1' , 'test_table_1'

drop table stg_table_1_old

Comment: @ Randi Vertongen. could you please also share your thoughts on the updated delete logic. I saw some peoples are deleting this way also.

Comment: @vikrantrana I updated the question (bottom) with your `select into` on my fabricated data. Apart from the notes on the `SCH-M` locks the result will be different from yours so it will not be that meaningful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Testing based on your comments

*Tested on SQL Server 2014 SP3*

> stg_table and stg_table_1 doesn't have indexes on service_date.
>
> both of these tables are loaded with million rows of data and delete
>   operation is taking lot of time.

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.st_table_1( stg_table_1_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                             service_date datetime2,
                            val  int)
CREATE TABLE dbo.stg_table (stg_table_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                            service_date datetime2,
                            val  int)
```

PK's + Clustered indexes on identity fields.

**DML**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.stg_table WITH(TABLOCK)
(
service_date,val) 
SELECT -- 1M
 DATEADD(S,rownum,GETDATE()),rownum
 FROM
 (SELECT TOP(1000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rownum
FROM master.dbo.spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master.dbo.spt_values spt2) as sptvalues

INSERT INTO dbo.st_table_1 WITH(TABLOCK)
(
service_date,val) 
SELECT -- 2.5M
 DATEADD(S,rownum,GETDATE()),rownum
 FROM
 (SELECT TOP(2500000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rownum
FROM master.dbo.spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master.dbo.spt_values spt2) as sptvalues

INSERT INTO dbo.stg_table WITH(TABLOCK)
(
service_date,val) 
SELECT -- 4M
 DATEADD(S,rownum,GETDATE()),rownum
 FROM
 (SELECT TOP(4000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rownum
FROM master.dbo.spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master.dbo.spt_values spt2) as sptvalues
```

2.5M rows in `dbo.st_table_1` and 5M rows in `dbo.stg_table`
(Almost) all of these 2.5M rows will be deleted by the query Which is a more than 10 times less than yours.

**Running your query**

[The actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkLAYZQfB) for your base delete statement

As expected `dbo.stg_table` is accessed twice to get the max & min values with a stream aggregate.
The cpu time & elapsed / execution time:

```
  CPU time = 4906 ms,  elapsed time = 4919 ms.
```

A missing index hint is added to the execution plan:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[st_table_1] ([service_date])
INCLUDE ([stg_table_1_ID])
```

**However**, when we add the index, an extra sort appears to delete the rows from this newly added index:

[image]

[The plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJRH9bXzH)

And the cpu time / elapsed time increases:

```
   CPU time = 11156 ms,  elapsed time = 11332 ms.
```

**YMMV**, but from my example, based on your comments about data, it did not improve the query.

**Creating an index on  `[dbo].[stg_table]`**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_service_date
ON [dbo].[stg_table] ([service_date]);
```

As a result the `MAX()` and `MIN()` can leverage the newly created index to return only one row instead of a full clustered index scan:

[image]

**With the execution time improved:**

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2609 ms,  elapsed time = 4028 ms.
```

And the [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hyzg6bmzH)

But this is only based on indexing & my own example. 
Proceed at your own risk.

---

**Extra Notes**

You should look into splitting that delete into separate batches so it won't fill up the log file & not having one big block of failed / succeeded delete .

You could also consider using `(TABLOCK)` so the entire table is locked from the very beginning.

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
delete dbo.st_table_1 WITH(TABLOCK)
where service_date between(select min(service_date) from stg_table)
                   and (select max(service_date) from stg_table);
```

---

**Update: `SELECT INTO` + `sp_rename`**

```
select * into db.temp_stg_table_1
from db.stg_table_1
where service_date not between( select min(service_date) from db.stg_table)
                             and (select max(service_date) from db.stg_table);

exec sp_rename 'stg_table_1' , 'stg_table_1_old'

exec sp_rename 'temp_stg_table_1' , 'test_table_1'

drop table stg_table_1_old
```

> how about if go with above logic to delete the millions of records.
>   any advantages and disadvantages with that.

Apart from performance, `sp_rename` needs a `Sch-M` lock to complete, meaning that it has to wait for all other sessions to release their locks on the table before it can be modified. Any indexes/constraints on the original table will be gone and you will have to recreate them.

When I run the query on my own data:

```
select * into dbo.temp_stg_table_1
from dbo.st_table_1
where service_date not between( select min(service_date) from dbo.stg_table)
                             and (select max(service_date) from dbo.stg_table);
```

This does not represent your data, keep that in mind.

It is reading all rows to return 0 which is not optimal.

[image]

With a high execution time:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 27717 ms,  elapsed time = 10657 ms.
```

But this is not really meaningful without more information regarding your data.
A query plan would be needed to give out more correct advice.

Comment: Thanks a lot Randi. my delete query is running fine now.

Comment: @vikrantrana great, good to hear! Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

[I would simply never delete 37 million rows in one statement](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes). This isn't about the execution plan you get - the overhead of finding rows to delete (whether you have parameter sniffing affect the finding of those rows or not) is far lower than the overhead of actually deleting them and logging those deletes. If you split this into chunks you can amortize that cost over time and process the deletes on a whatever-suits-your-fancy schedule instead of all at once.

```
-- you can play with these parameters to see what offers the best trade-off
DECLARE @BatchSize int = 10000, @TransactionInterval tinyint = 5;

DECLARE @s datetime, @e datetime, @r int = 1;

SELECT @s = MIN(service_date), @e = MAX(service_date) FROM dbo.stg_table;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

WHILE (@r > 0)
BEGIN
  IF @r % @TransactionInterval = 1
  BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  END

  DELETE TOP (@BatchSize) FROM db.st_table_1
    WHERE service_date >= @s AND service_date <= @e;

  SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
END

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

You might also consider delayed durability if you are on a modern enough version of SQL Server (see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/173324/1186) and [this blog post](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/melissaconnors/data-purge-with-delayed-durability)).

Answer (score 0):

Above query may perform ok because of Missing Index, but query is still wrong.

```
Declare @Fromdate DateTime
Declare @Todate DateTime

select @Fromdate=min(service_date),@Todate=max(service_date) 
from dbo.stg_table

SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
delete dbo.st_table_1 WITH(TABLOCK)
where service_date >=@Fromdate
                  and service_date <=@Todate
```

I took above example and executed without Index, it took 18 sec to delete 410792 rows.

If I create Index like above no doubts it will perform best.

1. So no `Sub Query` in `Where` condition,it may give `High Cardianility Estimate` in complex query.
2. Give more importance in writing  `Optimize query` than `index`.Both are important.

**Note :**

If performance is bad or worse because of `Parameter Sniffing` then only you should find suitable way to avoid `Parameter sniffing`,else you should IGNORE it.

After all not all `Store Procedure` is written with `OPTION RECOMPILE` .

As far as I understand ,in my script `@FromDate` and `@Todate` are not proc parameter they are local variable,so there is no question of `Parameter Sniffing`.

Comment: Thank you KumarHarsh. Could you please also share your thought on the approach as mentioned in above comment.   select * into db.temp_stg_table_1 from db.stg_table_1 where service_date not between( select min(service_date) from db.stg_table) and (select max(service_date) from db.stg_table);

Comment: If using parameters, I would add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the query as to make sql server 'see' the parameters at execution.  E.G. `delete dbo.st_table_1 WITH(TABLOCK)
where service_date >=@Fromdate
                  and service_date <=@Todate
OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. This will grant better estimates at the cost of recompiling the execution plan each time.

Comment: @RandiVertongen, No offence taken and with regard, I was not going so far like parameter sniffing problem etc.Read my edited Note onwards.

Comment: @KumarHarsh No problem :). However, that comment was not only about parameter sniffing. When declaring local variables like that, SQL Server will not know the value inside the variable when running the delete. This means that when creating the query plan an inneficient plan could be chosen instead of a plan for that specific value for `@Fromdate`and `@Todate`. More on that [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/)

Comment: @RandiVertongen,As per scope of this topic ,We are going very far.My answer is within the scope .

Comment: @KumarHarsh this isn't about parameter sniffing. See [this post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/). You answer is in scope, but you're leaving out a pretty big pitfall with doing things the way you're suggesting.